# Animation not rendering in sequence, first frame being repeated throughout the render

Tags: rendering, animation, osx

I am rendering a 240 clip animation (Blender 3.0.1) and the frames are not rendering in sequence.

Every few frames the first frame is rendered again in the sequence, replacing the frame that should be rendered. Eg clips 1-16 frames render fine and then instead of frame 17 being rendered, frame 1 will be rendered again.

I wonder if there is a setting or something that I have inadvertently clicked as I have never had this problem before?

[image]

Comment: can u pls provide blend file so we can check it out?

Comment: Thanks so much, where is the file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=n1Gr0nRD" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/n1Gr0nRD/)

Comment: after deleting the video file, you have to bake the particle system. you find this in the particle system tab > cache > bake [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THuyj.png

Comment: Thank you so much Chris. I have baked it and now it works! Much appreciated.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a particle system in your file.  There is a well known (to those who know it well) problem with Blender animation, that's documented (very obscurely) in the Blender manuals:  You *must* bake all physics, including particle systems, before attempting to render an animation.  I can dig up my attempt to file a bug report on this if you'd like to see gory details; but the developers will tell you "there's a known work around so it's not going to be fixed."

Baking should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much Marty. That worked, much appreciate the help.

Comment: @Fi_artist You are very welcome. Since you're apparently a new user to Blender StackExchange, you might want to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and perhaps accept my answer.